# can not import kafkaProducer in spark streaming job

Tags: python, linux, apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I have a simple `spark streaming` job that tracks an `HDFS` directory, read the newly added files, and send it to `Kafka`.

When submitting the spark job it does not work and throw the following exception.

> ImportError: cannot import name KafkaProducer

Here is the code of the job (http://pastebin.com/mpKkMkph)

The error is clear. The script can not import `kafkaProducer`.  The problem is that I can import it from the `python shell` without any problem.

Comment: Can you provide your kafka producer code snippet? It will be helpful for debugging the issue!

Comment: change your import statement from `from kafka import KafkaProducer` to `import kafka` **or** you can remove reference to kafka from your KafkaProducer initialization statement i.e your final statement looks like `producer = KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers="Broker_list")` . Hope this Solves your dependency issue!

Comment: I treid `import kafka` and I got this error `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'KafkaProducer'`. I tried to remove the kafka in producer initialization statement but the same error still exist.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I could solve the problem but the solution was very weird and I have no explanation to what happened.

I run this command `cat my_script.py > new_script.py` then I submitted the job using the new file.

Every thing worked fine but as I mentioned above I have no explanation to this issue.

Another thing to be noted here, copying the file using the normal `cp` command did not work also. Only `cat` the content to another file.

This is the second time I face this issue with python scripts I hope anyone have any illustration to it.